# Проблема с кликом

Tags: javascript

Почему надо кликнуть два раза по кнопке?

```
 function sords() {
     document.getElementById('new').onclick = function () {
         document.getElementById('sordas').setAttribute("class", "sordas");
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Создаётся элемент так:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('choise_area').innerHTML =  '
    <input id="new" value="Кликай" onclick="sords()" type="button"/>';
  return false;
}
```

Comment: а где вызывается функция sords?

Comment: написал сверху

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 раза, т.к.:

1. При первом клике ваш обработчик назначается
2. При втором вызывается

Что-бы было за 1 клик, можно как-то так:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('choise_area').innerHTML =  ''+
    '<input id="new" value="Кликай" onclick="sords()" type="button"/>';

  document.getElementById('new').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('sordas').setAttribute("class", "sordas");
    return false;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: а что дает innerHTML =  ''+, по сравнению с innerHTML = ''??

Comment: Ничего не дает ;)